# C++ -- which constructor of string is call when we use string(0)?

Tags: c++

Given the following code,

```
class A
{
public:
  A() : str(0) {}
private:
  string str;
};
```

Based on this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

```
string ( );
string ( const string& str );
string ( const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n = npos );
string ( const char * s, size_t n );
string ( const char * s );
string ( size_t n, char c );
template<class InputIterator> string (InputIterator begin, InputIterator end);
```

I don't see which constructor of string is called when we use the 'str(0)'.

Question> Can someone tell me which string constructor is used for 'str(0)'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one:

```
string ( const char * s );
```

It's converted to a null pointer. (And also gives you undefined behavior, since `s` cannot be a null pointer.)

Comment: @Cubbi: Yea, and I think MSVC gives a assert in debug builds. Strange requirement, though; I would have made a null pointer be equivalent to default construction.

Comment: @GMan: The trouble with that it would work on some implementations and fail on others. So I could build and test on Windows and it works. Then when I port to my mobile device which has a more conformant compiler it crashes unexpectedly with less opportunity to debug. I prefer the logical_error approach.

Comment: @Martin: Sorry, could you specify what you mean by "that"?

Comment: @Gman - Guess he means making it a default constructor as an extension. The rationale for undefined behaviour is of course that those who never construct from a null pointer should not have to pay for an extra test. If you suspect that you **might** have a null pointer, **you** can test for that `string s = p ? string(p) : string();`.

Comment: @Bo: But if my string isn't null, the compiler (being a smart compiler) knows it doesn't need to test anyway.

Comment: @Gman - I just give the rational. :-)  Remember that the interface was designed 15 years ago, when some of the compilers weren't that smart.

Comment: The better solution would have been a private `std::string::string(int)`. Catches this case, but doesn't affect the other overloads.

Comment: @MSalters But also works for any integral value, even an expression.  Since the only case we're concerned with is a null pointer constant (integral expression evaluating to 0), the best solution would perhaps be some other constructor, probably private, which accepts a pointer (to a possibly private type) or a pointer to member; constructing from NULL would then result in a compiler error.

Comment: @James Kanze: Note that I said "private". I don't care that `std::string(5)` _also_ fails to compile. It's OK to prevent other non-pointer expressions.

Comment: @GMan: By `that` I mean default constructing the string with a NULL pointer (special case). It gives a false sense of security. My preference would be that in Debug it throws an exception in release its UB. That way you should be able to catch the bug via unit tests. Best of all would be to update the standard as subsequent comments have described.

Comment: @Martin: I don't see how that will fail on some platforms, then. (I meant make that the standard requirement.)

Comment: @GMan: I mean. I could be developing on platform A where NULL causes the strign to be default initialized and all my tests work fine. Now I port it to platform B and here I get UB which can cause all sorts of problems especially if my primary debugging platform is A.

Comment: @Martin: Then B would be non-compliant, since null is suppose to default construct.

Comment: @GMan: Sorry I though you were saying (and I did not check) that the standard just treats it as a char* and thus is a UB because it will start searching for a '\0'. In that case my comments make no sense.

Comment: @GMan: Just checked. The standard says explicitly (n3092 but I am sure it is the same in most). That the pointer int the std::string constructor `shall not be NULL`. Thus it is platform A that is non conformant by default constructing the string (will UB means anything can happen I suppose that means default construction is allowed). But that makes my scenario above a pain. Is there another constructor that I am missing that takes integers?

Comment: @Martin: I'm suggesting a *change* to the standard, to make it so if `s` is null, instead of undefined behavior it must be equivalent to default construction.

Comment: @GMan: OK. Sorry for the crossed wires. I would prefer a change to the standard that throws std::<some exception> so we write code that is backward compatable with older compilers. (I work with modern on the desktop and old crappy compilers on device). So default construction on NULL would be a serious pain in my arss(deliberately misspelled in Jordy to prevent offense) for backward compatibility reasons. (See scenario above).

Comment: @Martin: Yea, that would be nice. But like @Bo says, they don't want people to pay for that if they don't need. (Understandably.)

Comment: @GMan: Your change is just as expensive as mine. I would prefer to maintain backwards compatibility. For me, just defining it in Debug would be fine so that release did not have to pay the price. Your change is `: init(s==NULL?"":s)` My change is `: init(s==NULL?throw X:s)`

Comment: @Martin: I agree it's as expensive. (But I also think, given a modern compiler, the check can be proven to be ignored in many cases.) I don't particularly agree with maintaining backwards-compatibility, but that tends to be the goal of C++.

Comment: @GMan: The thing is; this situation is quite common. The code I develop and test on the desktop works fine. Then it blows up in my face on the device where I have less debugging opportunities (ie its a lot harder) is not OK. In this kind of case it is a MUST to have good backwards compatibility (the device compilers are usually behind the main stream compilers). Saving you 2 seconds in extra typing is costing my a couple of hours of debugging. That's not a good trade off.

Comment: @Martin: But you're also an exceptional case. Not everyone works on lagging non-compliant compilers, and I personally don't think a correct way to maintain a language is to bend backwards for the few that do. However, since they want C++ to be used everywhere, they care about the minority as well, which works out well for the minority. I think this makes C++ a dead-end language. (I also think you could use an older compiler for your desktop, too; you aren't forced to use the newer language.)

Comment: @GMan: I have to disagree with my being the exception. Individual developers at home may be able to upgrade at will (I do). But in business this is not the case. Most people are using old(er) compilers. Especially when working on device rather than PC. I think I am the rule you are the exception.

Comment: @Martin: Perhaps; then my issue lies with society. :) Always seems to.

Comment: @GMan: I am way to old to be an exception. Society has long ago banged my into a hole and told me to conform (to old to argue against it now).

Answer (score 4):

It's using

```
string ( const char * s );
```

You're passing in a single argument and the argument isn't a const string reference so it has to be this version. The zero gets converted to a NULL pointer.

Comment: To explain this a little bit, the compiler is looking for a constructor that can be called with the arguments given. This means there must be one argument, optionally with more that have default arguments. There are two one-argument constructors. `const int` cannot be converted to `const std::string`, but it can be converted to `const char *`, which the constructor will then interpret as a zero-length character array (equivalent, but not equal to, `NULL` or `nullptr`).

Comment: I was wrong on one point: ISO/IEC 14882:2003 21.3.1 states that character pointers given to the constructors will not be null, but does not say what will happen. Therefor, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @John, in fact, it does convert 0 to NULL and I have confirmed this through debugging the code with VS2010.

Comment: @q0987: Correct, it will convert to NULL, but the standard says that the constructor does not accept NULL. So the code inside the constructor will have undefined behavior. That was what I was trying to say.